# Macro-generated pivot table throwing run-time error 5

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have an Excel report that requires many steps to prepare. To automate it, I recorded a Macro. I've been going through the generated code to do some minor fix-ups, such as creating a table from `CurrentSelection` instead of a hard-coded value and filtering on a calculated date instead of a hard-coded one.

When I got to creating the third pivot table in the process, I get the following error:

> Run-time error '5':
>
> Invalid procedure call or argument

The help suggests either an out-of-bounds value or something that's valid for one platform but not another. However, as this is generate code, neither of those should apply. Here's the relevant code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Table3", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "On Time Pivot!R3C16", TableName:="PivotTable12", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("On Time Pivot").Select
    Cells(3, 16).Select
```

I haven't touched this code, the first line of which is throwing the error. I don't normally work with VBA. I find the VBA documentation to be quite confusing and am at a loss as to how to debug this. Any ideas?

### Edit based on suggestions

Following the [link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables) in Sandor's answer, I changed the pivot table creation code thus:

```
Dim pvt_cache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim src_data As String
Dim pvt_location As String
src_data = "Table3"
pvt_location = "On Time Pivot!P3"
Set pvt_cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=src_data)
Set pvt = pvt_cache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=pvt_location, TableName:="PivotTable12")
Cells(3, 16).Select
```

I now get error 5 on the line where I call `CreatePivotTable`.

Comment: The macro recorder is kind of stupid here IMO, you should split the creation of the pivotcache and the pivot table into two steps.

Comment: Just a thought & may not be correct as happens when creating third table; are you changing the name of the table? You can't have two tables with the same name. Not sure if that's at sheet or book level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved, but in an unsatisfactory way. A different error randomly started appearing with a different pivot table regarding a filter being set incorrectly. Since I couldn't find anything wrong, fixing the filter manually every time I run the macro is no big deal, and it suddenly started appearing in code I hadn't touched, I surrounded it in `on error resume next` and `on error goto 0`. Immediately all error messages stopped and the macro has worked correctly since that time. I can't imagine how that could have fixed it, but I'm done messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()
'PURPOSE: Creates a brand new Pivot table on a new worksheet from data in the ActiveSheet
'Source: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String

'Determine the data range you want to pivot
  SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A1:R100").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create a new worksheet
  Set sht = Sheets.Add

'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
  StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
  Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="PivotTable1")

End Sub
```

Add your actual pivot settings (copy from recorded macro), for example a field2 sum to field1 strings:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("field2"), "Sum / field2", xlSum
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("field1")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

You can change the "Range" to the selected area coordinates,
for example the rows:

```
x = Selection.Rows(1).Row
y = Selection.Rows.Count + x - 1
```

But in this case unfortunately not only the filtered values will be in the pivot table, but you can create a filter to the pivot:

For example only visible if field2 = 6

```
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("field2")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("field2")
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(i).Value = 6 Then
                .PivotItems(.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = True
            Else
                .PivotItems(.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```

Change "=6" to between dates in correct dateformat.

**EDIT**

You can create a tmp sheet with filtered rows

```
Range("A:R").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Or combinate it with Selection.Rows and Selection.Columns and create pivot from tmp  sheet than delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've edited my post in response. In short, I think there's something else going on. Or maybe I'm just being dense.